# MS SQL create table with PK but PK already exists but table does not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the problem that i create a table + PK with a command like this:

```
  IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.mytable') IS NULL
BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mytable](
            [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
            [Data] [Varchar](20) NOT NULL
            CONSTRAINT [PK_mytable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
        [ID] asc
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
END
```

And i get the error message that PK_mytable already exists.
But the table mytable does not exist so i can´t delete the constraint using the following command:

```
alter mytable test DROP constraint PK_mytable
```

The constraint can be seen using this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'
and name like '%PK_mytable%'
```

I can rename the constraint but that seems to be a workaround solution especially if future changes to the table on different databases have to be changed because the constraint has a different name.

Sadly deleting the constraint using this doesn´t work

```
delete from sys.objects
where
type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT'
and name like '%PK_mytable%'
```

How do i get rid of the constraint?

Comment: *"How do i get rid of the constraint?"* [Delete Check Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/delete-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver16). `CONSTRAINT` names need to be unique; so the `CONSTRAINT` `PK_mytable` exists, but it's on a *different* table (to `dbo.mytable`).

Comment: Choose another constraint name. And consider a better naming convention.

Comment: What is the other table _not named `mytable`_ that contains a constraint called `PK_mytable`? You can only have one PK constraint with any given name in the entire database, regardless of what the table is called. So as suggested, use a better naming convention. If you have `schema1.mytable` and `schema2.mytable`, then maybe include the schema name in the PK name.

Comment: You can expand your query to find out the parent_id of the PK like this: `SELECT name, type_desc, OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), parent_object_id FROM sys.objects WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0 AND type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT' AND name LIKE '%PK_mytable%'`

Comment: Found the mistake: A table was renamed without renaming the constraint. That lead to the problem. Thx Jonathan Willcock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was that a table was renamed without renaming the constraint.

This command from Jonathan Willcock shows that clearly.

```
SELECT name, type_desc, OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id), parent_object_id 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0 AND 
type_desc LIKE '%CONSTRAINT' AND 
name LIKE '%PK_mytable%'
```